# How to transfer XML to a web service?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I learned that SOAP is a useful PHP library for sending information to wsdl web services.  I'm building an XML sheet to be sent to a webservice.  My friend made the web service, and he says it takes in a string of characters.  I'm trying to send him a string of an XML sheet, and when he copy pastes the XML, it's correct, but when I try to use the web service, all he gets is an empty pointer.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        //Product Id is called ProductID in the XML
        $product_id = $row['product_id'];


        //Final price is called SalesPrice in the XML
        $final_price = $row['final_price'];
        echo $final_price.'<br>';
        //qty is called Quantity in the XML
        $qty = $row['qty'];
        echo $qty.'<br>';
        //Purchase cost is called PurchaseCost in the XML
        $purchase_cost = $row['purchase_cost'];
        echo $purchase_cost.'<br>';

        $xml_output .="<SalesOrderLine>"; 
        $xml_output.='<ProductID>'.$product_id.'</ProductID>';
        $xml_output.='<Quantity>'.$qty.'</Quantity>';
        $xml_output.='<SalesPrice>'.$final_price.'</SalesPrice>';
        $xml_output.='<PurchaseCost>'.$purchase_cost.'</PurchaseCost>';

         // Escaping illegal characters 

        $xml_output.='</SalesOrderLine>';
        //$amount = $amount + $final_price;
        //$i++;
    }


    $xml_output .="</SalesOrder>"; 

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_output);
    $xml->asXML();
    echo $xml;

    try {  
    $client = new SoapClient("http://*&#^%(@%(*#(#$%)%CreateDB?wsdl");  
    $result = $client->addSalesOrder($xml);

} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump(libxml_get_last_error());
    var_dump($e);
}

    //$result = $client->addSalesOrder($xml_output);
    if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

When I echo out the entire $xml_output string, I can see it become an XML sheet by inspecting the code.  Both with and without using the SimpleXML library, passing the function to the web service does not work.  How do you safely transfer a string to a web service that's an XML sheet while keeping it as a string?

Comment: why do you create a SimpleXMLElement from a string and then immediatly turn it back into a string? ... also I think you need to assign it to some variable to actually do so like $strXML = $xml->asXML()

Comment: $xml_output .="</SalesOrder>";  ends but where is the starting tag? I mean     $xml_output ="<SalesOrder>";

Answer (score 0):

You can not send XML as Parameter for Soap Function. If you want to manipulate XML as input, use following way

```
// xml content

$xmlDocument = '<Result>

    <Product id="12345" language="fr-BE">

        <Data>

            <Brand>BrandName</Brand>

            <ProductName>Bag</ProductName>

        </Data>

    </Product>

</Result>';

// initiate soap client

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient(
        "http://dotnetwebservice.com/Products.asmx?wsdl",

        array(
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => 1,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
            'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
            'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
        )
);

$xmlvar = new SoapVar(

      "<ns1:xmlDocument>'.$xmlDocument.'</ns1:xmlDocument>", XSD_ANYXML 
);

$params->xmlDocument = (object)$xmlvar;

$save_result = $client->SaveProduct($params);
```

Please find more details on link http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php