# How to post xml or array to .svc webservice in php using soap

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hi I am trying to post my xml to a function 'SendBillPaymentAdvice' of a web service with the url `http://stageserv.interswitchng.com/uat_quicktellerservice/QuickTeller.svc?wsdl` using soap but I keep getting the error that my xml is not in the correct format. Tried so many format but it won't just work!.
How can I correctly post my xml to the function. The following is my excerpt:

```
$xmlData=<<<DATA
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<BillPaymentAdvice>
<Amount>10000</Amount>
<PaymentCode>1***</PaymentCode>
<CustomerId>080***9</CustomerId>
<CustomerEmail>luvysols@gmail.com</CustomerEmail>
<TerminalId>3****01</TerminalId>
<RequestReference>123456789</RequestReference>
</BillPaymentAdvice>
DATA;

$wsdl = 'http://stageserv.interswitchng.com/uat_quicktellerservice/QuickTeller.svc?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl)
$result = $client->SendBillPaymentAdvice($xmlData);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer 
[PHP SOAP - How do transfer XML to a web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722288/php-soap-how-do-transfer-xml-to-a-web-service/11734138#11734138)

You can not pass XML string as Parameter to Web Service directly.